# What is the IP address(es) that send the traffic from parse.com to my MongoDB URI?

Tags: parse-platform

I have already migrated my app but there still are users that use the old parse url, which then sends the traffic to my self-hosted databse. I need to whitelist parse's IP range so that my MongoDB is not exposed to anyone.

I have already found an answer [here](https://www.parse.com/questions/cloud-code-ip-address) that mentions:

> you can try whitelisting the IP addresses currently published by Amazon for AWS US-East

I need to know whether this answer is still relevant.

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you setup a user and a password? IP addresses are not 100% reliable especially when it involves cloud services like parse and aws.

Comment: I already use user/password authentication, I need this as an extra security measure.